# Emitting a single IR bitcode File with LLVM LLD using CMake

Tags: cmake, llvm, lld

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 and LLVM 5.0 and would like to compile a project to a single LLVM IR bitcode file using CMake. I know there is a way to do this using the GOLD Linker with the LLVM Plugin and add the CMake linker flags "*-fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-plugin-opt=emit-llvm*" and the CXX flag "*-flto*".

But when I try to compile the project with the LLVM LLD linker and the "*-fuse-ld=lld -Wl,-plugin-opt=emit-llvm*" respectively "*-flto*" Flag, the linker is generating a native executable and no LLVM IR file. I was searching for other LLD options to emit a LLVM IR file but found nothing.

Is there a way (or option) to generate a single LLVM IR file using LLD?

Comment: Are you sure this is not working for you? I didn't try this myself, but this article promises it should work: http://gbalats.github.io/2015/12/10/compiling-autotooled-projects-to-LLVM-bitcode.html.

Comment: Yes the GOLD Linker can emit a single LLVM IR file. But I would like to have the ability to generate a single LLVM IR bitcode file OR a native executable. The project should link to a static LLVM IR Library and the GOLD Linker can't link to it while generating a native executable. So the LLD Linker can do this, but I don't know how to generate a LLVM IR file with the LLD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-save-temps` option.

```
clang -flto -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,-save-temps a.o b.o -o myprogram
```

This will generate `myprogramXYZ.precodegen.bc` among other files. You can then use `llvm-dis` to get it in readable IR format.