# LLVM IR for a large C project

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, gold-linker

I'm new to LLVM, clang etc.
My primary need is to convert C code to LLVM IR (.ll) then parse this to a assembly-like language. For this I was till now working with small length c codes (single file) and to get these converted to LLVM IR I used -

```
$ clang -emit-llvm -S multiply.c -o multiply.ll
```

To do this conversion with a large C project, I tried gllvm - https://github.com/SRI-CSL/gllvm
and it was really easy & convenient but I am facing this issue with it - https://github.com/PLSysSec/sys/issues/16
which basically a bug in the llvm-hs repo essentially asking me to pull the commit which has the fix and build it. I'm trying to avoid doing this (is this a better way ?)

So I moved onto another solution of using the gold linker - http://gbalats.github.io/2015/12/10/compiling-autotooled-projects-to-LLVM-bitcode.html

I am now stuck on using this gold plugin to get .bc or .ll files -  I want to use this gold plugin to convert a large C project into .ll or .bc files - but the steps only show how to use the linker to get optimised executable. Are there any command line options to only convert it till .bc files ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your question it's not clear what are you trying to achieve. Are you compiling several small C files into LLVM-IR and then you want to link them all into a single IR file ? If that's the case, you could link them using the llvm-link binary. This is great if you control the build scripts being used. If you don't, you could compile with -fembed-bitcode, generate the final binary files as-usual, and extract the embedded bitcode (in the .llvmbc section in ELF binaries), and link all the bitcodes again with llvm-link.

Comment: thanks for your response @jmmartinez I am trying to compile a large C project into .ll files or .bc files - I will also modify the question and make it more legible

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to generate a single whole-program LLVM-IR for each binary (executable or dynamic-library) in the project. Then, you can compile with `-flto -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,-save-temps`: 1) this will enable LTO for LLVM (so each generated object file contains in fact bitcode); 2) when linking, you'll be using the LLVM linker lld that can corretly handle LLVM-IR and 3) the `-Wl,-save-temps` flag will make lld keep the temporary bitcode files used while linking (they have some suffixes such as .preopt.bc, .internalize.bc and .precodegen.bc). You can then use those.

Comment: This may be related to what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957981/emitting-a-single-ir-bitcode-file-with-llvm-lld-using-cmake

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this with a large project, For eg openssl, which has a build script  (./configure) or is it better to go with tools like gllvm https://github.com/SRI-CSL/gllvm for autotooled projects, given that I have limited time ? and it would take longer to modify large build scripts

Comment: Oh ! Yes. If you have limited time, I think you'll be better off by picking the fix from gllvm.

Answer (score 0):

The `llvm-link` tool combines multiple .bc files into a single .bc. It does not support native object files at all, nor does it work well with normal linker flags (it does not pretend to be `ld`).

If you do want changes to the llvm IR due to your native libraries on the system, the gold plugin to llvm also supports a `emit-llvm` flag. Run a clang or gcc link with `-Wl,-plugin-opt=emit-llvm` when linking with gold.